# NodeJS WebSockets routing messages from devices to Angular gui through NodeJS

Tags: node.js, websocket, angular-cli

I've created a NodeJS application that implements a socket manager like so:

```
import { Server } from "ws";
import clientObj from "../objects/clientObj";
import serverObj from "../objects/serverObj";
 
class socketMgr {
  serverA = undefined;
  serverB = undefined;
  confA = undefined;
  confB = undefined;
  
  init(cA, cB) {
    this.confA = cA;
    this.confB = cB;
  }
  
  serve()
  {
    // server between devices and nodejs
    if (this.confA.host && this.confA.port)
    {
      this.serverA = new Server({ host: this.confA.host, port: this.confA.port });
      this.serverA.on("connection", connection => new clientObj(this.confA, conn));
    }
    // server between nodejs and gui
    if (this.confB.host && this.confB.port)
    {
      this.serverB = new Server({ host: this.confB.host, port: this.confB.port });
      this.serverB.on("connection", conn => new serverObj(this.confB, conn));
    }
    return true;
  }
}
export default socketMgr;
```

This manager declares and initializes two socket servers that send and receive messages. The whole flow goes like this (simplified on a 1 to 1 approach):

```
device (clients written in native C++ or other, no GUI) <==> NodeJS client/server <==> gui client (devices running Win, iOS or Unix based OS)
```

1. device connects to NodeJS and creates a client (that implements event listeners) on serverA
2. client on serverA replies to the handshake request from the device
3. when handshake is successfull, device starts emmiting messages periodically to NodeJS (client on serverA)
4. NodeJS client processes messages and saves some states to the DB (sql), not entire messages because that would be an absolute overkill

**TODO:**
Once a message is processed on the serverA client, that message has to be emmitted somehow to the corressponding gui client (hosted on a different port).

This is the fun part where web sockets serverB comes into place. I don't really know if this is the right approach but I'd like to use ServerB instance to re-route/broadcast to the gui. Many devices (hundreds or even thousands) will eventually send messages like this and many users can watch these messages from the gui side (monitoring).

Can re-routing/broadcasting messages to the gui be achieved without the serverB instance?

How can I achieve this type of re-routing/broadcasting of messages in NodeJS?

EDIT: This issue is a lot more complicated than my first estimation showed. Devices have to communicate through two web socket servers and connections must be managed separately because these devices on both sides aren't equal in any way. Routing between them must be handled programmatically.

If I can provide any additional info. on the subject, please let me know.

Thank you for looking into this.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create two server for this. Device and GUI both is client. When device emits data to server you can send this data to GUI by allowing subscribing GUI client to device messages, by topic name or by device ID.

Comment: That approach requires observer design pattern and guessing socket.io integration?

Comment: if you want to use native websocket you can use third party pub/sub js library

Comment: You can read this tutorial https://hackernoon.com/create-your-own-pubsub-client-server-use-websocket-65dd1820e997

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'll look into it.